# Get Image and append it elsewhere

Tags: jquery

I need to grab an entire image in one div, remove it and append it to another div. The image source will always be different so I will need to account for that. This is what I have so far, I'm pretty sure this isn't correct. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<div class="content">
    <img src="123410928510934587.jpg" />
    <img src="45646513513515.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var imgRetrieve = $('.content img:first').find('img').attr('src')
$(document).ready(function() {
    imgRetrieve ();
    $('.sidebar').append();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively simple:

```
$('.content img:first').appendTo('#target_element');
```

Comment: Wow, now I feel like a total idiot. It was much more simple than I thought.

Comment: @JJ Nold: how are you trying to trigger this particular jQuery call? **Edited** it worked after all?

Comment: @David in a document.ready function. I have it appending, now I just want to remove it from the initial div. I imagine that I use .remove() in this case.

Comment: @JJnold why do you want to remove and add in the document.ready , that means you want it by default right.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't word it right. Forget I mentioned the document.ready. I essentially want to remove it from the .content div and add it to the .sidebar div.

Comment: @JJ Nold: according to the [API reference for `appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) it should be automatically removed and then inserted at the target.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for your help. I'm still a big jQuery noob but I am falling in love with the power it offers.

Answer (score 0):

JJ

The following code should get html from old div and apply to new div.

```
var oldDiv= $('#oldDiv').html();

$('#newDiv').html(oldDiv);
```

.html() will replace the complete html of new div , if you want to append you can use append

```
$('#newDiv').append(oldDiv);
```

Comment: .html() will replace the complete html of new div , if you want to append you can use append.

Comment: @david , hi david , how are you??

Comment: busy with work , but spending sometime on SO as i like this very much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I put it in a click handler, but it doesn't have to go there:

```
$('.content').click( function() {
    $('.content img:first').appendTo('#sidebar');
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cLEE6/